# Issues with instantiation of string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11

I'm having issues with instantiating strings and passing an array to another function. Yesterday, I had the following code and it was working fine:

```
string sources[8][3] = {
    {"ab", "cd","ef"},
    {"gh", "ij","kl"},
            (...)
}
```

I want to pass the *sources* array as a parameter to another function which must have the following prototype:

```
size_t parse_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, char *userdata){
```

So the variable will be userdata, that I would cast into an array of arrays of strings. I decided to use pointer, but I can't do better than that :

```
string** sources;
sources = new string*[8];
sources[0] = new string[3];
sources[0][0] = new string("ab");
```

Is there a more elegant way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: Which part of the `sources` array are you trying to pass, as what argument?

Comment: The code is conceptually wrong. You can't cast a string[][] type to a char* type. Either you convert string[][] to an array of C strings, or you change `parse_data` arguments.

Comment: Can you change the parameters of parse_data? And what is the function supposed to do?

Comment: Remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers. So by just doing an explicit cast of `sources` to `char*` when calling, and when using it you cast it back to a pointer to an array of three strings and it should work fine. ***Unless*** the function actually expects the passed `userdata` argument to be an actual C-style string.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : there is probably some other conceptual problem to be addressed here

Comment: @gd1 no I can't The function is actually a callback, and is executed when some data is received by cURL. cURL imposes this prototype.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, that's exactly what I'm planning to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do it the way you are doing. But, since you list `C++11`, the static [`array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) can be instantiated with the following:

```
#include <array>
...
array<array<string, 3>, 8> sources;
```

Which is all on the stack, so no need to dynamically allocate strings.

Populating an entry could be done with `sources[0][0] = string("foo");`

You can populate everything at once using [`initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

```
 array<array<string, 3>, 8> sources { "ab", "cd","ef", "gh", "ij","kl",
                                      (...)};
```

You would call `c_str()` on the array item, when passing along a c-style string pointer to `parse_data`.

E.g.: `sources[0][0].c_str()`

---

**Full example code:**

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int, char **)
{
  array<array<string, 2>, 3> sources { "ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", "ij", "kl"};

  for (size_t i = 0 ; i < sources.size() ; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0 ; j < sources[0].size() ; ++j) {
      std::cout << i << "," << j << ": " << sources[i][j] << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0,0: ab
0,1: cd
1,0: ef
1,1: gh
2,0: ij
2,1: kl
```

Comment: FYI, you can also do `sources[0][0] = "foo"` which seems more natural to me.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this as soon as I can and let you know.

Comment: @gd1 that's what I did it the example I mentioned in the question, but that's not elegant as there are 24 values.

Comment: @user1319182 : That's not quite what you did in the example when you used `new` 3 times, if that's what you are referring to. Of course filling in the array by using `sources[i][j]` is inelegant, I was just pointing out that `sources[0][0] = "foo"` is the same as `sources[0][0] = string("foo")`, due to converting constructors, as a nitpicking comment to what @swalog suggested.

Comment: So thanks for the syntax, as it works fine, but my problem is not solved because I can't pass the argument to the function. Here is the error message I get : cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘struct std::array<std::array<std::basic_string<char>, 3ul>, 8ul>’ through ‘...’

Comment: @user1319182 If you actually intend to pass the `source` directly to the function, you are going about this wrong. You can send *one* `std::string` to the `parse_data` function, and you convert it to a null-terminated c-style-string using `c_str()` before doing so. If you want to somehow concatenate all the `std::string` items in the 2d-array, you have to do that prior to sending it on to `parse_data`. As I said in the beginning, I'm not entirely sure why you are doing this the way you are. Perhaps you can share that motivation.

Comment: @user1319182 If you want to mess around with passing binary data to a callback function and `reinterpret_cast `the type back to something meaningful, you need to have all the data contiguous in memory, and know where it starts and ends. An array of `std::string` is not good here, as they are dynamic containers, and point elsewhere. If the data is kept alive by other means, you can get by with a simple pointer... I'm really curious about the code you had yesterday, which you say was working.

Comment: In other words, passing binary data to a callback function and using `reinterpret_cast` is similar to defining your own binary format. You could pass a blob of data where the first 4 bytes denotes the number of inner strings, followed by sequences of {4 bytes denoting the length of the string in bytes, followed by the N bytes with the string}. Then, pass a pointer to where that blob starts, because you can now calculate exactly how many bytes it uses in memory... Or something along those lines. Hard to solve a problem without knowing what the problem actually is :)

Answer (score 1):

Taking from the previous answer by **swalog**, you can also do this

```
std::array<std::array<std::string, 3U>, 8U> strings
{{
    {{"ab", "cd", "ef"}},
    {{"gh", "ij", "kl"}}
}};
```

in order to fully mimic your original (and very neat) syntax.

Why the double braces you may ask? `std::array` is basically an array wrapper, so the first brace says "Initialize a `std::array` structure" and the second brace says "Initialize the internal array with these values". And then you have an `std::array` of `std::arrays` so you need to multiply this logic by two...

Downside to this idea is that auto-formatting IDEs don't like this very much, but unless you're making some high numbers of dimensions, you should be OK.

**Edit:**
In order to pass these values as `char*` you need to reinterpret cast a pointer to the array:

```
char* userData = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&strings);
```

and then reinterpret back to `std::array<std::array<...>>*`:

```
auto array = *reinterpret_cast<std::array<std::array<std::string, 3U>, 8U>*>(userData);
```

And then, obviously, if the caller returns before the data is used (e.g. calls a function in different thread to use the data), you need to allocate all the data on the heap, but I guess that'd be enough for another question thread...

Comment: Thanks. However I still have a problem because I can't pass the array as a parameter, and that's why I wanted to use pointers in the first place. I get this error : cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘struct std::array<std::array<std::basic_string<char>, 3ul>, 8ul>’ through ‘...’